# Why is screen width the same on ipad mini and normal ipad

Tags: ios, swift

When this code is called it gives the same result on ipad mini and normal ipad

```
var bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
var width = bounds.size.width
```

and it shouldn't be the same the normal ipad's width should be bigger the the ipad mini screen width

in my game i have an imageview that moves by using uiview animations and changing nslayoutconstraint constant in a certain duration

And i change the size of the square so that it will be fair to players with any device i use this code

```
Movew.constant=((35*self.view.bounds.width)/411)
Moveh.constant=((35*self.view.bounds.width)/411)
```

And these will make the imageview size the same on the normal ipad and on the ipad mini
Will it be fair to the players

Answer (score 1):

iPad, iPad Air, iPad Pro 9.7" and iPad mini have same resolution, so your code should return same values.
The difference between iPads and iPad mini screens is density. iPad mini has smaller display so density is bigger, on other iPad density is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of all iPads are the same (2048 x 1536), with the exception of the 12.9" iPad Pro.

http://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/

Answer (score 0):

The unit of measure for the bounds is points, not pixels or inches.  The size in points for both devices is the same.

If you need to know about pixel dimensions, see the `scale` method.

Comment: Even when is multiply it by the scale it will still be the same value

Comment: Entirely possible if both devices are the same in terms of retina / non-retina.

Comment: Im am making a game and i set the size of the image view based on screen width and on the ipan mini it will be easier than the normal ipad

Comment: @WajdiMuhtadi  What unit of measure do you want your answer in?

Comment: I dont care i need a code that i can call to get screen width and it will be bigger for the normal ipad

Comment: Not caring doesn't change the answer to your question: they are the same as far as code is concerned.  The way they're different is their external measurement and there's no API for that.

Answer (score 0):

It probably because the resolution of the iPad and iPad Mini are the same. `UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds` gives you the pixel space, not the screen size.

Check here for the resolutions.
 http://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/

Comment: How can i get the resolutions programmatically

Comment: `UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds` gives you the resolution of the device running your app.

Comment: I used it and it is the same resolution

Comment: Thats because all iPads have the same resolution except the 13" Pro.

Comment: That is why im asking i need a code that will make the normal ipad width bigger

Comment: I don't think theres a way to get screen width from the iOS libraries. `UIDevice.model` or `UIDevice.localizedModel` should give you the model of the device. You could build a dictionary that maps model with screen width.

Comment: I dont want to do that because every time a new device is made i will have to update the app to support it

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what's in the other answers, and expand on it a bit:

All iPad models except the 12.9" iPad Pro have the same logical screen resolution (1024 x 768 points, 2048 x 1536 pixels), even though the 9.7" models (iPad, iPad Air, iPad Pro 9.7) and the iPad mini differ in physical size. The iPad mini has a higher pixel density — more points per inch — than the rest.

There's no API that will tell you a device's physical dimensions (or points or pixels per inch) because it's not supposed to matter. For example, the iOS Human Interface Guidelines say to make sure that tap targets are at least 44 points in size, regardless of whether you're designing for the 163 points per inch of an iPhone or iPad mini, the 144 points per inch of a 9.7" iPad, the 140-ish points per inch of an iPhone 6/6s in Display Zoom mode, the who-knows-how-many points per inch of some new device, etc.

If you have a UI design that doesn't work well on an iPad mini, then your design doesn't work as intended *for all users* on a 9.7" iPad either.